# Visual Studio Team Services - Deny view of Tasks

Tags: permissions, azure-devops

I have been looking for a way to deny a certain group the ability to see TASKS. I still want them to be able to see TICKETS. Is there a way to do this? I have been reading about permissions in VSTS, but I have not yet found anything specific to this particular question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to deny specified users view tasks of work items for now.

But there has an user voice [Hide Work Item Types (WITs) based on permission/security group](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/2085675-hide-work-item-types-wits-based-on-permission-se) which suggest enable to set permissions for work items types for different groups. You can vote and follow up for the user voice.

When this feature is available, then you will deny users in a group to view tasks.